# Python lists outside of range

Tags: python, list

How can I move forward an item in the list past its range? For example, If I set an alarm at 2pm and I want it to go off in 59 hours, what time will it be?

I would like my code to look something like this, but it fails past the range of 25:

```
time = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
print(time[15+59])
```

Comment: @metatoaster It will give you 2

Comment: If I wanted to change this to an input function (user can select time and how many hours to skip ahead) what would be the most efficient code for doing so? Because my code for it seems longer than it needs to be. (I replaced 15 and 59 for 'input' as well as the corresponding code to make its syntax corret

Comment: `time = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
print(time[(int(input("What time?")) -1 + int(input("How many hours?"))) % len(time)])`
This is my code for the input version, any better ways than this?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Python, but modular arithmetic:

```
print(time[(14 - 1 + 59) % 24])
```

prints

```
1
```

Comment: Ah see, so basic I was just over thinking thank you, and thank you Patrick Allen

Comment: Should be (14 - 1 + 59).  14 is original hour, -1 is because of zero based indexing, and 59 is the offset.  The correct answer is 1 am.

Comment: @Alexander Right, I assumed that it was 4pm since the OP wrote it as [15 + 59], but fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo to get the remainder of the index you want divided by the length of the tuple:

```
 time = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
 print(time[(15+59) % len(time)])
```

Answer (score 0):

[np.roll](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) shifts all of the values in your iterable, and thus answers your original question.

```
import datetime as dt

>>> dt.datetime(2016, + dt.timedelta(hours=59)
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 4, 1, 0)  # 1 a.m.

>>> np.roll(time, -59)[14 - 1]  # -1 because of zero based indexing.
1  # 1 a.m.
```

For example:

```
>>> np.roll(time, -1)
array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
       19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,  1])
```

Of course, I would still go with the simpler answer using modulo, i.e.

```
time(hour - 1 + hour_offset) % 24.
```